# Need help fixing a strange path error in bash

Tags: 64-bit, compatibility, 32-bit, libraries

I have two executable files I downloaded and am trying to add to the path. They are located in

```
/home/user/folder
```

and the specific files are

```
/home/user/folder/app1
/home/user/folder/app2
```

Both app1 and app2 have the executable flag set to all (user, group, other).

I can execute the files if I am in /home/user/folder and I execute these commands

```
./app1
./app2
```

However I can't run them from elsewhere. I added this line to my .profile

```
PATH="$PATH:/home/user/folder"
```

and then sourced the path with

```
. /home/user/.profile
```

and I can see app1 and app2 when I use command completion (pressing tab). However here is what happens when I try to run app1 or app2 with the following commands (the following only shows 'app1' but the same is true of 'app2')

```
user@comp:~$ app1
-bash: app1: command not found
user@comp:~$ /home/user/folder/app1 
-bash: app1: command not found
user@comp:~/folder$ ./app1
(program runs)
```

I'm stumped :), I must have missed something simple. Thanks for your help!!

**UPDATE**

Ok, I found some errors in the path which I think I fixed, but now it's not running in any case - which for some reason I think is a step forward. Thanks for suggesting the following steps, here is their output:

```
user@computer:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/share/fsl/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games:/usr/local/matlab/bin:/usr/local/VoxBo/bin:/usr/local/itt/idl64/bin:/usr/local/afni/bin/:/usr/local/mricron:/usr/lib/voxbo/bin:/home/user/folder:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11/:/usr/games/:/usr/local/matlab/bin:/usr/local/VoxBo/bin/:/usr/local/itt/idl64/bin:/usr/local/afni/bin/:/usr/local/mricron/
user@computer:~$ typeset -p PATH
declare -x PATH="/usr/share/fsl/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games:/usr/local/matlab/bin:/usr/local/VoxBo/bin:/usr/local/itt/idl64/bin:/usr/local/afni/bin/:/usr/local/mricron:/usr/lib/voxbo/bin:/home/user/folder:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11/:/usr/games/:/usr/local/matlab/bin:/usr/local/VoxBo/bin/:/usr/local/itt/idl64/bin:/usr/local/afni/bin/:/usr/local/mricron/"
user@computer:~$ type app1
app1 is /home/user/folder/app1
user@computer:~$ type app2
app2 is /home/user/folder/app2
user@computer:~$ app1
bash: /home/user/folder/app1: No such file or directory
user@computer:~$ app2
bash: /home/user/folder/app2: No such file or directory
user@computer:~$ /home/user/folder/app1
bash: /home/user/folder/app1: No such file or directory
user@computer:~$ /home/user/folder/app2
bash: /home/user/folder/app2: No such file or directory
user@computer:~$ cd /home/user/folder
user@computer:~/folder$ app1
bash: /home/user/folder/app1: No such file or directory
user@computer:~/folder$ ./app1
bash: ./app1: No such file or directory
user@computer:~/folder$ ./app2
bash: ./app2: No such file or directory
user@computer:~/folder$ ls -l
total 29384
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 14949776 2011-02-03 11:09 app1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 15137300 2011-02-03 11:10 app2
user@computer:~/folder$
```

Thanks for everyone's input!

Comment: What does `type app1 app2` output? What do you mean by `/somedir/app1`? wasn't app1 in `/home/user/folder`?

Comment: @geirha by 'somedir' I ment a directory other than /home/user/folder. type app1 and type app2 returns the following: app1 is a hash (/home/user/folder/app1) and app2 is /home/user/folder/app2. Thanks!

Comment: What is `gdw`?  Is it `app1` or something else?

Comment: @Mikel yeah app1 is actually gdw which is used by a program called voxbo :) - sorry about the typo! In my last comment 'gdw' should be app1. (should be fixed)

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show exactly what you are typing and the error you see?  Confirming what directory you are in and how the command is being run should help.

Comment: @Mikel I reworded my question. I hope it makes more sense. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please re-run your tests, but first run `echo $PATH`, `typeset -p PATH`, and `type app1` in the same terminal, and paste the output of those as well as `app1`, `/home/user/folder/app1`, `cd`, and `./app1`.

Comment: I'm stumped too. I can only think of two things. Either there's a bug with your shell, or you are accidentally omitting vital information when censoring the filenames.

Comment: @Mikel Thanks for suggesting those steps, I already corrected one error in the PATH and I'm now thinking there may be more because it's no longer running the app in any situation. I edited the question to show the output.

Comment: @Jorge Castro done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know some of this is repetitive.... but...

Edit your BASH RC file:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

**Export** the PATH:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/$username/folder/
```

If you don't want to log in again to get the path, SOURCE it:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Make sure the file is yours and executable:

```
chown -R $username /home/$username/folder/
chmod +x /home/$username/folder/app*
```

Try to run:

```
cd
app1
app2
```

Still have the *command not found* error? Well, what kind of files are app1 and app2?

```
file /home/$username/folder/app1
file /home/$username/folder/app2
```

If they are text files, it could be that they are scripts, like BASH or Python. If so, open them up with an editor to see if you can glean the source of the problem. If you paste any of the contents of the text files (if, indeed, they are text files), be sure to please include the very first line - the "file magic" like *#!/bin/sh*, for example.

Comment: I think the 'file app1' command did the trick. The file is a ELF 32 bit LSB executable and I'm using a 64bit Ubuntu box. I think that's probably the problem?

Comment: Oh! So... Does 'getlibs' solve the problem? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=474790

Comment: WOW! Worked like a charm. Thanks so much your help!

Comment: @Evan. Ah, if you had said the error message was `No such file or directory` from the start, instead of `command not found`, which is a completely different error message, that'd be my first guess. So you did accidentally omit vital information by censoring the filenames.

Comment: @geirha sorry about that, the whole thing confused the heck out me because I knew it had to be something simple in the end. I actually ran the second set of tests (the output I added in the update) after a reinstall so both of us wish I had a clearer picture sooner :). Good old computers...

Comment: Wahoo! Mission accomplished.